# VIM: match number following PATTERN, replace with number + 1

Tags: regex, vim

I have a set of lines that look like:

```
 $AERDIR/aergen.sh -n control -s 2100 -e 2120 -m 3 -a -x -z 144 -p  -g
 $AERDIR/aergen.sh -n Cl26E10 -s 2100 -e 2120 -m 3 -a -x -c 2.6E-10 -z 145 -p  -g
 $AERDIR/aergen.sh -n Br26E12 -s 2100 -e 2120 -m 3 -a -x -b 2.6E-12 -z 146 -p  -g
 $AERDIR/aergen.sh -n I26E13  -s 2100 -e 2120 -m 3 -a -x -i 2.6E-13 -z 147 -p  -g
```

I would like to match the three digit number after -z and replace it with that number +1, so

```
 $AERDIR/aergen.sh -n control -s 2100 -e 2120 -m 3 -a -x -z 145 -p  -g
 $AERDIR/aergen.sh -n Cl26E10 -s 2100 -e 2120 -m 3 -a -x -c 2.6E-10 -z 146 -p  -g
 $AERDIR/aergen.sh -n Br26E12 -s 2100 -e 2120 -m 3 -a -x -b 2.6E-12 -z 147 -p  -g
 $AERDIR/aergen.sh -n I26E13  -s 2100 -e 2120 -m 3 -a -x -i 2.6E-13 -z 148 -p  -g
```

I've been playing around with submatch parameters and such, but have only managed to increment the first appearance of numbers in each line. How would I formulate a command to do this, say from line 203,$  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for [`submatch`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#submatch()):

```
%s/-z \zs\d\+/\=submatch(0)+1/
```

The pattern `-z \zs\d\+` matches one or more digits `\d\+` preceeded by `-z`. Then `\=submatch(0)+1` adds one to the matched number.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the syntax on how to match the z flag the first time around. Much appreciated.